# Anyone had success installing GE V7 orV6 on Artful Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, google-earth

Ubuntu 17.10 just underwent an upgrade and erased Google-earth-stable_current_amd64. None of the available installs, either .deb, synaptic, or repository will activate and run this app.

Has anyone had success installing Google-earth either V7 or V6 on Ubuntu 17.10 Artful? I'd like to know any details if it was more involved than apt install .